# "плавное" обновление ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Есть код, который выполняет обновление списка пользователей

```
function OnlineUpdate() { 
    $('.gc-tab-online').html(''); 
    $.ajax({url:'/api/index/62',dataType:'xml',cache:false,async:false,success:function(data) { 
        $('member:contains("USER_NAME")',data).each(function(){ 
            var apiID = $(this).find('value').text(); 
            var apiXml = $.ajax({type:'GET',url:'/api/index/8-0-'+apiID+'',dataType:'xml',async:false}).responseText;
            var userAva = $(apiXml).find('member:contains("USER_AVATAR")').find('string').text();
            var userLink = $(apiXml).find('member:contains("USER_PROFILE")').find('string').text();
            var userName = $(apiXml).find('member:contains("USERNAME")').find('string').text();
            var userGroup = $(apiXml).find('member:contains("USER_GROUP")').find('string').text();

            if(!userAva) var userAva = '/gameChat/noava.png';

            $('.gc-tab-online').append(
                '<div class="gc-online-user">'+
                '<div class="gc-online-userava">'+
                '<img src="'+userAva+'">'+
                '</div>'+
                '<div class="gc-online-userinfo">'+
                '<div class="gc-online-username">'+userName+'</div>'+
                '<div class="gc-online-usergroup">'+userGroup+'</div>'+
                '</div>'+
                '<div class="gc-online-usersend"></div>'+
                '<a href="'+userLink+'" class="gc-online-userpage" target="_blank"></a>'+
                '</div>'
            ); 
        });
    }});
}

OnlineUpdate(); 
setInterval(OnlineUpdate, 15000);
```

На странице выглядит, что список дёргается..
Видны пользователи, пропадают, появляются через время.
Как можно выполнить эту процедуру более "плавно"?

Comment: Или как реализовать, чтобы пользователи которые **"пришли"** добавлялись, а которые **"ушли"** удалялись?      P.s. максимум их 30 штук

Comment: ссылка на сайт, если что вот [ссылка](http://school-site.clan.su/) (не обращайте внимание на всё остальное, кроме чата :3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function OnlineUpdate() { 
   $.ajax({...success:function(data) { 
      $('.gc-tab-online').html(''); 
      ...
        var $newDiv = $('<div class="gc-online-user" style="display:none">'+
            ...
            '</div>');
        $('.gc-tab-online').append($newDiv);
        $newDiv.fadeIn(1000);
```

Comment: Всё равно мерцает :С

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 В других браузерах наблюдается мерцание?

Comment: @Anamnian, нет возможности проверить в других браузерах, наблюдается в лисе.

Comment: ссылка на сайт, если что вот [ссылка](http://school-site.clan.su/) (не обращайте внимание на всё остальное, кроме чата :3)